# Javascript: selecting all checkboxes on a page. It checks all for a second and then disappears

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a view that renders a partial view.
Index.cshtml contains a partial view.

The div below exist in the partial view

```
            <div id="sa-da">
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/><span>@T("Select / Deselect all invoices")</span> 
                <div class="payinvoices"><input class="amebtn" id="PayInvoices" type="button" text="Pay Invoices"  onclick="RemovePagination();"/> </div>
            </div>
```

I am using the method below to turn off pagination on a grid(webgrid) in the partial view with the use of a click of a button

```
            function RemovePagination()
                 {      
                    UpdateGrid("","clkPayInv");
                    $('#invoicestatus').val('unpaid');            
                    SelectAllCheckboxesOnLoad();
                 }
```

I want the function below to select all the checkboxes on the click of the button as well

```
             function SelectAllCheckboxesOnLoad()
             {
                var aa= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
                    if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox')
                        aa[i].checked = true;
                }

             }
```

?? The checkboxes are checked on the click of the button but it does not remain checked.
It just flickers for a second showing all the boxes checked and then it disappears.
How can I fix this?

```
            function UpdateGrid(searchString,whatWasClicked) {
                    $jq.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Invoices")',
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: false,  
                        data: { status: $("#invoicestatus").val(), from: $("#from").val(), thru: $("#to").val(), search: searchString, payInvClickBtn:whatWasClicked},
                        dataType: "html",
                        global: false,
                        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) { if (jqXHR.status == 401) { window.location.replace(location.href); } } ,
                        success: function (result, status, hr) {
                            $('#Grid').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurrs because your ajax call isn't completed at the time you trigger the check/uncheck.
Place the call to

```
SelectAllCheckboxesOnLoad();
```

inside the success method, after

```
$('#Grid').html(result);
```